# Facebook unable to retrieve iPhone Store ID?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set up an iOS 6.0 and up app on Facebook developers, everything's hooked up and working fine using the latest SDK. The problem is that, though authentication works fine, later in the app it's requesting post permissions and when a Facebook account is **not a member** of the Facebook app in the Dev center, these permissions aren't requested, the screen just pops to Facebook and back to the app again without doing anything. When I try to use the app with my account that is an admin on Facebook Dev, then it works.

The posting action in question is a Facebook Graph post and it works fine for the admin account.

In previous apps I haven't requested publish permissions through the Facebook developer portal in the app settings (you know, the app review bit by Facebook), so that can't be it either. Those apps work with accounts that are not a member.

I know the code is fine, the code is re-used from previous apps.

I think it's because I am unable to enter the proper Facebook app ID in the Settings. Could that be the cause? Though the app ID is in iTunes Connect, Facebook can't find it yet because the app in review at Apple.

Any thoughts on this nightmarish user rights issue?

Comment: Since API v2 was introduced, with every new app you need to go through review for any extended permission (apart from the three basic ones) – otherwise you will only be able to ask users that have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for those permissions.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I want to flag it as such, but cannot, since it's a comment. Thank you, good sir!

Comment: Added it as an answer, together with some extended information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API v2 was introduced, with every new app you need to go through review for any permission apart from the three “basic” ones (those are `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends`) – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

Otherwise you will only be able to ask users that have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for permissions – that is helpful either during testing, or for an app that is for a limited user base only; f.e. if you want your app to publish updates from your website to your Facebook page, which requires `manage_pages` – in such a case you should not submit for review, but just use that permission with your admin/developer/tester account associated with the app. That is further explained here – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#apps-all-users-are-developers